# Array notation or .method() - which is faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I came across the array notation in JavaScript, and I wondered which way would be faster or better to write. I think the second version is harder to read, but are there any benefits of it ? Or does somebody use this way of calling the methods? Or is there no difference between those regarding their speed?

- `$('#myContainer')['addClass']("active");`
- `$('#myContainer').addClass("active");`

I am used to doing it the second way, but is the first way faster or are there any other benefits of using the first version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSPerf: http://jsperf.com/brackets-vs-dot-notation

According to the perf, the bracket notation is faster in some browsers.

This is a kind of micro-optimalisation which you should **avoid**. Choose the notation which feels the **most comfortable**.

Comment: Your test isn't really that relevant, it's for object property access, not function calls. This test: http://jsperf.com/brackets-vs-dot-notation/2 imitates how jQuery creates an object more faithfully and shows `.` being faster in that case.

Comment: Ah, well, not in Firefox 10 apparently :)

Comment: @minitech Look again, Firefox says that the bracket notation is faster. And, it is still about property look-ups. Both methods involve function calls, which can only be done once the properties are known. The performance difference can be neglected though, the last phrase of my answer is much stronger ;)

Comment: @RobW: Calls are optimized, though. Or so I thought. :P (And yeah, I still gave you a +1)

Answer (score 3):

No, the first version is used when you're dynamically accessing some unknown property, or when the property contains special characters. Using the bracket notation will make your code harder to write, probably worse to minify, and less efficient to run. Don't do it.

Also, it's ugly :)

---

P.S. The bracket notation isn't a magical jQuery feature. It's part of JavaScript.

Comment: yeah its definitely ugly :D also for people who have to understand your code afterwards and don't know that this is available !

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the javascript engine that runs the code, but since they both get compiled to exactly the same code, I really doubt that there'll be any *significant* performance differences.

When optimizing code, focus on loops, not on trivial things such as this :)

Comment: yeah thanks, I'm not optimizing code I just wondered if this is a "common" way because I have never seen it in any way !